# Design for Multilevel and hierarchical State Machines

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-machine

There are scenarios in Network programming that you need State Machines with multiple and hierarchical depths.

```
State Machine 1
     State Machine 2

     State Machine 3
          State Machine 4
```

Here State Machine `1` contains two state machines `2` and `3`. `3` also contains a machine `4`.

Based on the state of the outer machine, the message should pass through the inner state machines. Also if there is some error in the inner state machines the feedback should be given to upper machines.

Is there a good approach to do this?

Right now I have a jungle of if statements and flags which do this for me. I keep facing problems that some flag is not set due to which whole state of the state machine goes in a unrecoverable state.

**UPDATE:**
I am trying to keep the states and the machine static. As the request will pass through the machines and states, request itself will store all the meta data required. In this case normal State Machine pattern does not help.

Answer (score 0):

[State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to separate state and *Context*. *Context* can store the hierarchy of the states and state subclasses themselves are unaware of this hierarchy. All the if statements are gone because each section under if goes into a separate state subclass.

Comment: I have tried to use State but does not seem to work for such design. Actually my program flow switches back and forth between machines also. Like on one event I am in inner machine but for the next event I need to be in the outer machine. And that is what creates major problem.

Comment: You should read the GOF book on Design Patterns. Implementing State transitions that you talk about is addressed in the Implementation section. I will summarize it for you: State transitions can be implemented entirely in Context or in State subclasses. You should choose where to implement by asking questions like: Are the number of states fixed or will more be added?